# Taking tab example from fiddle ans use in my project

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

http://jsfiddle.net/738wtmhs/1/

using above example in fiddle in my own project: for the purpose of this exercise I am using DOM methods to create and append the elements.

```
    function GetFeatureProperties(feature) {

    //add header to 1st FirstTabContent
    var featureHeader = "<center><b> <FONT COLOR='FF6600'> Feature Properties </FONT> </b> </center> </br>";
    var FirstTabContent = document.createElement('div');
    FirstTabContent.id = "tabs-1";
    FirstTabContent.innerHTML = featureHeader;

    //Second Tab
    var SecondTabContent = document.createElement('div');
    SecondTabContent.id = "tabs-2";
    var newImage = document.createElement("img");
    newImage.src = "http://mintywhite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/fond-ecran-wallpaper-image-arriere-plan-hd-29-HD.jpg";
    newImage.width = "100";
    newImage.height = "100";
    SecondTabContent.appendChild(newImage);

    //add li and ul
    var DivHolding2Tabs = document.createElement('div');
    DivHolding2Tabs.class = "shoptab";
    var header2 = document.createElement('h2');
    header2.innerHTML = "Feature";
    DivHolding2Tabs.appendChild(header2);

    var _ul = document.createElement('ul');

    var _anchor1 = document.createElement("a");
    _anchor1.href = "#tabs-1";
    _anchor1.innerHTML = "Info";
    var _li1 = document.createElement('li');
    _li1.appendChild(_anchor1);

    var _anchor2 = document.createElement("a");
    _anchor2.href = "#tabs-2";
    _anchor2.innerHTML = "Images";
    var _li2 = document.createElement('li');
    _li2.appendChild(_anchor2);

    _ul.appendChild(_li1);
    _ul.appendChild(_li2);

    DivHolding2Tabs.appendChild(_ul);
    DivHolding2Tabs.appendChild(FirstTabContent);
    DivHolding2Tabs.appendChild(SecondTabContent);

    var jelm = $(DivHolding2Tabs); //convert to jQuery Element
    var htmlElm = jelm[0]; //convert to HTML Element

    var OuterDiv = document.createElement('div');
    OuterDiv.id = "loc-list";
    OuterDiv.appendChild(htmlElm);

    return OuterDiv.innerHTML;

}
```

and this looks like the image seen below....if I click on the link 'image' the page jumps a bit but nothing happens and nothing happens when I press 'info' also I have included the CSS in my project so why arnt the tabs showing and yes I am using jquery ui 1.10.3.custom.js

[image]

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**UPDATE**

```
<ul id="list"><li><div><h2>Feature</h2><ul><li><a href="#tabs-1">Info</a></li><li><a href="#tabs-2">Images</a></li></ul><div id="tabs-1"><center><b> <font color="FF6600"> Feature Properties </font> </b> </center> <br></div><div id="tabs-2"><img src="http://mintywhite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/fond-ecran-wallpaper-image-arriere-plan-hd-29-HD.jpg" width="100" height="100"></div></div></li></ul>
```

Also changed from jquery 1.10.3 custom to jquery 1.11.2.custom with all the downloaded tabs selected

Comment: I'll need the exact HTML you are using.

Comment: Also, in your jquery ui custom, you have he core and the tab widget?

Comment: thanks for the reply Ive updated the answer to include what data is past back in the OuterDiv.innerHTML and yes my JQuery custom DID INCLUDE core and tab widget, BUT for the sake of testing iv also just updated jquery to 1.11.3 full version with all tabs downloaded + i thought Jquery might have been the problem so I amended the 'divHolding2Tabs' inside a jQuery element and converted to html in my code....does any1 have any suggestions as to why it isnt working? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7x4wxhj3/3/), I managed to make it work.

Here's the possible problems

1) I changed return OuterDiv.innerHTML because I needed the `<div id="loc-list">` to be part of the code to initialize it. You gave it an id so my guess is you wanted it to be included but by doing innerHTML, you didn't get it.

2) Once your function returns, you need to initialize the tabs with `$('#loc-list').tabs();`

Comment: ahh great job....thanks for the reply and taking the time to help but for the purpose of this exercise I need it to be returned in innerhtml, also I dont need an id in the loc-list, iv now removed it altogether and returned the htmlEle...please see http://jsfiddle.net/7x4wxhj3/4/ ....shouldht this have worked>

Comment: @John No it can't work because you're not initializing the tabs. Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7x4wxhj3/5/. I'm appending your .innerHTML to the #container and then initializing the tabs.

Comment: Ahh thats great thanks for all your help...but its still not quite there...Iv marked this answer as correct as it has answered my original Q, but now working on from that I have hit another wall....if you get a chance maybe you will take a look ta http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060008/jfiddle-showing-up-different-in-application